# frunk's foldl against elements that share same trait with different type parameters

Tags: rust

I'm learning how to use [frunk in Rust](https://beachape.com/frunk/frunk/index.html).

I have a question on how to use  the`folder` argument of the [foldl method](https://docs.rs/frunk/0.2.2/frunk/hlist/struct.HCons.html#method.foldl) against *elements that share same trait with different type parameters*. I wrote an example below with seemingly-redundant `folder` parameter (this example compiles just fine) of foldl method.

Is there a simpler way to pass `static_forward` function to `foldl`?

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate frunk;

trait Layer<InDim, OutDim> {
    fn forward(&self, input: Vec<InDim>) -> Vec<OutDim>;

    fn static_forward(input: Vec<InDim>, layer: &Self) -> Vec<OutDim> {
        layer.forward(input)
    }
}

struct FtoI {}
struct ItoF {}
struct FtoS {}

impl Layer<f32, i32> for FtoI {
    fn forward(&self, input: Vec<f32>) -> Vec<i32> {
        // In real case, converts the input to output.
        vec![1, 2, 3]
    }
}

impl Layer<i32, f32> for ItoF {
    fn forward(&self, input: Vec<i32>) -> Vec<f32> {
        // In real case, converts the input to output.
        vec![1., 2., 3.]
    }
}

impl Layer<f32, String> for FtoS {
    fn forward(&self, input: Vec<f32>) -> Vec<String> {
        // In real case, converts the input to output.
        vec![String::from("Hello"), String::from("world")]
    }
}

fn main() {
    let vec_float = vec![1., 2., 3.];
    # These elements share Layer trait with different type parameters
    let layers = hlist![FtoI {}, ItoF {}, FtoS {}];

    let r = layers.to_ref().foldl(
        hlist![
            // All of the element are same and seem redundant. Can this argument be simplified?
            Layer::static_forward,
            Layer::static_forward,
            Layer::static_forward
        ],
        vec_float,
    );
    /* This doesn't compile due to "type mismatch in function arguments "
    let r = layers.to_ref().foldl(Layer::static_forward, vec_float);
    */
    println!("result: {:?}", r);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got an idea from @1tgr about using macro. The below is my implementation. This requires manually defining '@cons' part for every 'N' that may be invoked, and  specifying "3" in macro argument.

Still I'm looking for a better solution.

```
macro_rules! hcons_repeat {
    (@cons (0, $_e:expr))
        => { HNil };
    (@cons (1, $e:expr))
        => { HCons{ head: $e, tail: hcons_repeat!(@cons (0, $e))}};
    (@cons (2, $e:expr))
        => { HCons{ head: $e, tail: hcons_repeat!(@cons (1, $e))}};
    (@cons (3, $e:expr))
        => { HCons{ head: $e, tail: hcons_repeat!(@cons (2, $e))}};
    (@cons (4, $e:expr))
        => { HCons{ head: $e, tail: hcons_repeat!(@cons (3, $e))}};
    (@cons (5, $e:expr))
        => { HCons{ head: $e, tail: hcons_repeat!(@cons (4, $e))}};
    (@cons (6, $e:expr))
        => { HCons{ head: $e, tail: hcons_repeat!(@cons (5, $e))}};
    (@cons (7, $e:expr))
        => { HCons{ head: $e, tail: hcons_repeat!(@cons (6, $e))}};
    [$e:expr; $n:tt] => {
        {
            hcons_repeat!(@cons ($n, $e))
        }
    };
}

...

let r = layers
    .to_ref()
    .foldl(hcons_repeat![Layer::static_forward; 3], vec_float);
```